# Pyomo optimization Investments/Revenue

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, maximize

I'm new to Pyomo and I'm trying to optimise investments depending on budgets.
I have a total budget, and I want to find the best way to split the budget on the different medias.
eg: total_budget = 5000 --> tv = 3000, cinema = 500, radio = 1500.

I'm struggling "connecting" a Budget with a corresponding Revenue.
The medias have different return curves (It might be better to invest in a specific media until a certain budget is reached, then other medias).
The revenue for the different media is returned by a function like the following:    `tv_1k_revenue = calculate_revenue(budget=1000, media="tv")`
Let say the only constraint I have is the total budget to simplify the problem (I can manage other constraints I think).

Here is my code so far:

```
model = pyo.ConcreteModel(doc="Optimization model")

# Declaration of possible budgets
model.S1 = Set(initialize=[*df.TV_Budget.values])
model.tv_budget = Var(model.S1, initialize=0.0)
model.S2 = Set(initialize=[*df.Cinema_Budget.values])
model.cinema_budget = Var(model.S2, initialize=0.0)
model.S3 = Set(initialize=[*df.Radio_Budget.values])
model.radio_budget = Var(model.S3, initialize=0.0)

# Objective function
def func_objective(model):
    objective_expr = sum(model.tv_revenue +
                         model.cinema_revenue +
                         model.radio_revenue)
return objective_expr

model.objective = pyo.Objective(rule=func_objective, sense=pyo.maximize)
```

So my problem is, how do I declare model.tv_revenue, model.cinema_revenue, model.radio_revenue so I can optimise TV, Cinema and Radio budgets to maximize the total revenue generated by TV, Cinema, Radio?
Right now I created a DataFrame with a Budget and Revenue column for each media, but the best way should be using my `calculate_revenue` function and set `bounds=(min_budget, max_budget)` on each media budget.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There's not enough info here to help you.  Are the "budgets" just a single amount each?  It seems you are struggling with *indexing* them.  Is that required?  Are there budgets in time periods or ?.  If you add some additional info on the nature of the problem, what you are trying to do with it, and add a snippet of the dataframe, that would be helpful.  :)

Comment: I'm agree with @AirSquid. There is not enough information about data sets, parameters and constraints.

Comment: @AirSquid
I added some more details, I hope it helps. 
Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

From what you are providing and your limited experience w/ `pyomo`, here's my recommendations...

You appear to have budgets and revenues, and those appear to be *indexed* by media type.  It isn't clear what you are doing now with the indexing.  So I would expect something like:

```
model.medias = pyo.Set(initialize=['radio', 'tv', ... ])

model.budget = pyo.Var(model.medias, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
...
```

Throw `pandas` out the window.  It is a great pkg, but not that helpful in setting up a model.  Try something with just `python` dictionaries to hold your constants & parameters.  (see some of my other examples if that is confusing).

The problem you will get to eventually, I'm betting, is that your revenue function is probably non-linear.  Right?  I would start with a simple linear approximation of it, see if you can get that model working, and then consider either making a piece-wise linear approximation or using a non-linear solver of some kind.

===================
Edit / Additional Info.

Regarding the obj function, you *cannot* just stuff in a reference to a non-linear function that returns a value.  The objective needs to be a valid `pyomo` **expression** (linear or non-linear), comprised of model elements.  I would start w/ something like this...

```
# media mix

import pyomo.environ as pyo

# data for linear approximations of form revenue = c1 * budget + c0

#           media      c0  c1
consts = {  'radio' : (4,  0.6),
            'tv'    : (12, 0.45)}

# a bunch of other parameters....??  limits, minimums, etc.


### MODEL

m = pyo.ConcreteModel('media mix')

### SETS
m.medias = pyo.Set(initialize=consts.keys())


### VARIABLES
m.budget = pyo.Var(m.medias, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)


### OBJ
m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=sum(consts[media][1]*m.budget[media] + consts[media][0] for media in m.medias), 
                sense=pyo.maximize)

m.pprint()
```

#### Yields:

```
1 Set Declarations
    medias : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    2 : {'radio', 'tv'}

1 Var Declarations
    budget : Size=2, Index=medias
        Key   : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        radio :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
           tv :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals

1 Objective Declarations
    obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
        None :   True : maximize : 0.6*budget[radio] + 4 + 0.45*budget[tv] + 12

3 Declarations: medias budget obj
```

Comment: *" Try something with just python dictionaries to hold your constants & parameters"* or he can create an `AbstractModel` and create instance with the dat file.

Comment: @Corralien I agree, however, I think getting started it is *much* easier to just set up the data in pure python, which is brilliant at sets & dictionaries (or even at reading in large data files) rather than Abstract model, which can be much tougher to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @AirSquid !
That's exactly it.
It does make a lot of sens to throw pandas in my case.
Also, Yes my revenue function is non-linear.
I might try to make a linear approximation and see if I can make that work.
I was going to try to declare my objective function as:

```
def func_objective(model):
    objective_expr = sum([calculate_revenue(model.budget[media], media=media) for media in model.medias])
return objective_expr
model.objective = pyo.Objective(rule=func_objective, sense=pyo.maximize)
```

Would you know why I cannot declare it like this?

Comment: see my updated answer above regarding this question.